# Django url validation

Tags: python, django

HI,

I want to validate my urls whether they are post or get with caring the proper data.So i want to validate these urls before they call to respective views.So i am willing to write the some kind of middleware between view and urls so that i can keep safe the system.I am not aware how do i pass the data through middleware code to view.In middle ware i will write the unittest code.which will validate the urls if valid then will pass to the respective view other wise happy to say 404 .So can any buddy suggest me how do i handle the case.Or may be their is another alternative best way to do this validation.

Thanks to all.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want to simple check `request.method` which a view (or using a view decorator)? Furthermore, you can't tell whether a request is a POST message from the URL alone, let alone determine what POST data it carries.

Comment: "I want to validate my urls whether they are post or get with caring the proper data."  That's what view functions do.  "i want to validate these urls before they call to respective views".  That is **not** how Django is supposed to work.  What is the point of breaking the way Django works?

Comment: Agreed. This is *not* something you should be doing, anyways, which is probably why you're having so much problem. Like most frameworks, doing the right thing in Django is almost always *easy*. If you're facing significant challenges, you need to step back and evaluate your logic. Like @S.Lott said, this is what the view is made for; use the view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should really be checking for request type in your views, and not in a middleware. As I mentioned in the comments above, you can't tell whether a request is a POST message from the URL alone, let alone determine what POST data it carries.

Checking the request type within a view is very straight-forward -- simple check that `request.method` is equal to `"GET"` or `"POST"`.

If you're doing this often, a short cut would be to create a decorator which does this check for you. For example, the following decorator checks that a GET request was used to call this view, or else return an `HttpResponseBadRequest` object (status code 400):

```
# untested code, use with care
def require_GET(view_func):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method != "GET":
            return HttpResponseBadRequest("Expecting GET request")
        return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    wrap.__doc__ = view_func.__doc__
    wrap.__dict__ = view_func.__dict__
    wrap.__name__ = view_func.__name__
    return wrap
```

You can then simply prepend your view function with `@require_GET` and the check will be done whever the view is called. E.g.

```
@require_GET
def your_view(request):
    # ...
```

You can do the same for POST.

Here's an example decorator checking for POST request which takes an optional list of fields that must be provided with the POST request.

```
# again, untested so use with care.
def require_POST(view_func, required_fields=None):
    def wrap(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method != "POST":
            return HttpResponseBadRequest("Expecting POST request")
        if required_fields:
            for f in required_fields:
                if f not in request.POST:
                    return HttpResponseBadRequest("Expecting field %s" % f)
        return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    wrap.__doc__ = view_func.__doc__
    wrap.__dict__ = view_func.__dict__
    wrap.__name__ = view_func.__name__
    return wrap
```

Use like this:

```
@require_POST
def another_view(request):
    # ...
```

or:

```
@require_POST(required_fields=("username", "password"))
def custom_login_view(request):
    # ...
```

### Update

OK, my bad. I've just reinvented wheel.

Django already provides the `@require_GET` and `@require_POST` decorators. See [django.views.decorators.http](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/decorators/#allowed-http-methods).

Answer (score 2):

Like others said, you must do it in your view, or maybe you must say what you are trying to do for the best...

Anyway, you can not create a responce object in **process_request** , you can only add variables or change variables on the related request, like the *sessionid* variable used by django, or any such thing... Or update any existing request variables...

So, you must use process_view, which is triggered after process_request and just before your related view function is executed.Since you have request object at hand, you can check GET or POST data by using **request.GET** or **request.POST**.

For doing this, you must add your middle class to **MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES** in settings.py  and write a proper middleware **process_view** function. For writing middlewares see [middleware documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/middleware/#middleware) and check existing middlewares of django. Or tell me what you are rtying to do...